# I want to create a supply chain using hyperledger fabric, but I don't know what to do first

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to create a supply chain using hyperledger fabric, but I don't know what to do first. what should i do? If you have any recommended lectures, please recommend them. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/bevel/tree/main/examples/supplychain-app/fabric/chaincode_rest_server/chaincode/supplychain)(Supply Chain example).

Hyperledger Bevel is an accelerator that helps developers rapidly set-up and deploy secure, scalable and production-ready DLT network.

---

Follow this step

1. Build Hyperledger Fabric Network (using Hyperledger Bevel / If you want to test, you can use [docker-compose](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html))
2. Make dApp (Supply Chain using chaincode / Custom [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/bevel/tree/main/examples/supplychain-app/fabric/chaincode_rest_server/chaincode/supplychain))
3. Test or Something

---

If you're new to Hyperledger Fabric, I recommend trying the [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/getting_started.html)